# SQL Server - Using a column alias in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

I have the following query which works fine with MySQL but refuses to work with SQL server:

```
SELECT table1.someField AS theField, 
       COUNT(table2.someField) / (SELECT COUNT(someField) FROM table1 WHERE someField = theField),
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.someField = table2.someField
```

SQL Server doesn't seem to like the alias in the subquery. I've been told I need to use a CTE but I've never used them before. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might well be in the confusion in the sub-query

```
SELECT COUNT(someField) FROM table1 WHERE someField = theField
```

the `someField` in the condition will be local - but you can get to `table1.someField` just the same.

How about

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.someField) FROM table1 t3 WHERE t3.someField = table1.someField
```

?